# What is the difference between soda water and water?

Tags: nutrition, water, drinks

Assuming both water and soda water come from the same tap water source, and the soda water does not have any additives or flavoring. (aka not pop)

What effect would soda water have on the human body compared to plain water?

Comment: You are talking about carbonated water, right?

Comment: In Australia, it is carbonated water with Sodium Hydrogen carbonate so it is rather basic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chemically speaking, carbonated water is j**ust plain water with carbon dioxide dissolved** in it under high pressure.

- It hydrates just as well as normal water, because it still contains plain H2O.
- There are no additives.
- It might have a [slightly larger effect on erosion of teeth than normal water](https://books.google.de/books?id=cIhPAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT998&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=carbonated%20water&f=false) because it is [just a little bit acidic](http://www.thuisexperimenteren.nl/science/carbonaatkinetiek/Carbondioxide%20in%20water%20equilibrium.doc).
- The effect on the gastro-oesophageal reflux disease [is little to none](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2036.2010.04232.x/abstract;jsessionid=8AF28D926E52FBD3DD7CEBED1003740E.f04t04).

---

**Sources**:

1. Joan Gandy, *Manuel of Dietary Practices*, [Chapter on Dental Erosion](https://books.google.de/books?id=cIhPAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT998&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=carbonated%20water&f=false)
2. T. Johnson et al., *Systematic review: the effects of carbonated beverages on gastro-oesophageal reflux disease*, [Wiley Online Library](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2036.2010.04232.x/abstract;jsessionid=8AF28D926E52FBD3DD7CEBED1003740E.f04t04)

---

**Further Reading:**

1. [Livestrong](http://www.livestrong.com/article/156879-health-effects-of-carbonated-water/)
2. [Healthline](http://www.healthline.com/health/food-nutrition/is-carbonated-water-bad-for-you#1)
3. [New York Daily News](http://www.nydailynews.com/life-style/health/sparkling-water-healthy-regular-water-article-1.1460179)