# Relationship between carbonated water intake and cavities?

Tags: dentistry, oral-health

How does the intake of carbonated water with sugar additives correlate with the incidence of cavities? Is carbonated water itself corrosive?

Comment: Are you thinking of plain-ol-carbonated water or soda with sweetener? The carbonate itself has little to none effect on anything, artificial sweetener in carbonated imposes is the same risks as artificial sweetener in non-carbonated water.

Answer (score 2):

### There is no difference between real and added sugar.

Glucose (C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub>) as an example can be an additive or a "original" nutrition of any natural product.

Carbonated water with sugar additives therefore has the same increasing chance of caries (and cavities) as the same amount of sugar as what companies might advertise as "Carbonated water with real sugar". 
[Recent research](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2010/08/17/health/17real.html?referer=) has found that the amount of time spent consuming sugar has a larger effect on the risk of cavities than the amount.

---

[This previous answer of mine](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/12972/8212) talks about the corrosiveness of carbonated water and comes to the conclusion that

> carbonated water might have a [slightly larger effect on erosion of teeth than normal water](https://books.google.de/books?id=cIhPAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT998&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=carbonated%20water&f=false) because it is [just a little bit acidic](http://www.thuisexperimenteren.nl/science/carbonaatkinetiek/Carbondioxide%20in%20water%20equilibrium.doc).

Answer (score 1):

About sugar-sweetened beverages (SSB), the ingestion of 1-2 SSB  daily increment the caries incidence at least in 31% ([Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24813370))

The use of carbonate drinks without sugar added increase the incidence of dental erosion ([source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28176000)).

Hence, any carbonated liquid is associated with dental erosion. If you add sugar, then is also associated with dental caries.

Comment: Your second source seems behind a paywall and the abstract is beautifully uninformative for the question at hand. Could you expand what you read there and cite a bit more?

Comment: Hm, that paper: I suspect that they used the American definition of "carbonated **soft** drinks" -> including things like coke under that label. It is further unclear how just adding CO2 to H2O could be that influential. Do you agree in reading that table as carbonated drinks being the weakest erosive agent?